# How to find the values is sum of what all days

Tags: sql

I have a column where we are storing the sum of selected date values .. for example I have fixed date value below

```
1  Sunday
2  Monday
4  Tuesday
8  Wednesday
16 Thursday
32 Friday
64 Saturday
```

in my column I am getting 12 so its clear that user has selected `(4)Tuesday+(8)Wednesday=12`

now I have 106 what logic I can write to find out what combination of days is it?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Bitwise operators are not supported on all RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
  ( (SelDates &  1) =  1) AS IsSun,
  ( (SelDates &  2) =  2) AS IsMon,
  ( (SelDates &  4) =  4) AS IsTue,
  ( (SelDates &  8) =  8) AS IsWed,
  ( (SelDates & 16) = 16) AS IsThu,
  ( (SelDates & 32) = 32) AS IsFri,
  ( (SelDates & 64) = 64) AS IsSat
FROM <table>
```

This should work both in MySQL and SQL-Server, as they both support the & bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like this (MS SQL, Bitwise AND):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (daySum & 1) = 1 THEN 'IsMonday' 
CASE WHEN (daySum & 2) = 2 THEN 'IsTuesDay' 
CASE WHEN (daySum & 4) = 4 THEN 'IsWednesDay' 
... etc ...
END FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can get the bitmap directly with the `BIN` function

```
SELECT LPAD(BIN(106), 7,'0') --> 1101010
```

The MSB is saturday, the LSB sunday